# Программное создание контролера или варианты реализации меню с подменю на UITableView

Tags: xcode, ios

Добрый день!

Имею идею создать список пунктов меню на UITableView. По клику на cell должен совершаться переход в подменю, то же из UITableView и так далее. Глубина подменю заранее не известна и в процессе варьируется.   
Начал делать так: создал в сториборд TableViewController для корневого меню и от него через segue для меню первого уровня. И тут понял, что заранее неизвестно количество таких переходов.
Помогите решить эту проблему. Может, есть какие-то патерны для подобных проблем или создание контролера и сегвея возможно программным путем (если да, то как?) либо вообще это решается по-другому?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать segue на самого себя.
И передавать в tableViewController пункты меню которые необходимо отобразить.
Т.к. изначально мы имеем массив, элементом которого является название пункта меню и список подменю (который тоже массив и в нем все тоже самое).
И на каждом шаге передавать все меньший и меньший массив.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил отказаться от использования storyboard и делать все программно.